# Best way to pass a ConcurrentHashMap to another class?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton, concurrenthashmap

I have a handler class that contains a private ConcurrentHashMap which other classes want, but I'm not sure the best way to give it to them.

My apparent options are..

1. Return the entire ConcurrentHashMap (sample code below--this sounds dangerous to me, given that CHMs are meant to be used by only one thread at a time)
2. Create a new HashMap every time you want to return the whole thing.
3. Return an iterator... but I hate iterators! And it would only be just the keys or the values.

> ```
> public class StuffHandler {
>     private StuffHandler(){}
>     public static synchronized StuffHandler getInstance() {
>         return INSTANCE;
>     }
>     private final static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Stuff> myStuff = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
>     public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Stuff> getStuff() {
>         return myStuff;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: "CHMs are meant to be used by only one thread at a time" - no? the *entire point* of the Concurrent data structures is that they can be used by more than one thread at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the best way to pass a* `ConcurrentHashMap` *to another class*. It all depends on your use case, i.e. on what you want your classes to do.

You have three options:

1. Return the map as is:

   ```
   return myStuff;
   ```

   This will let your other classes modify the actual `myStuff` map and everyone will see the changes. However, **there won't be any concurrency issue**, since `ConcurrentHashMap` actually supports concurrent access (hence its name), and it does it in a very efficient way.
2. Return a copy of the map:

   ```
   return new HashMap(myStuff);
   ```

   This returns a fresh new map to every class that calls your `getStuff()` method. So every caller can play around with this map, since no one else will see modifications, neither other caller classes nor your `StuffHandler` class. Keep in mind that if the map is big, *it might result expensive* to return a copy every time its getter is called.
3. Return an unmodifiable *view* of the map:

   ```
   return Collections.unmodifiableMap(myStuff);
   ```

   This does not return a copy of the map. Actually, it doesn't copy anything, but returns a wrapper of your map instead, which doesn't allow modifications. This is transparent to the classes that call `getStuff()`. This option returns a live view of the map, so the actual `myStuff` map won't be modified (if a modification over the returned map is attempted, an `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown). Nonetheless, if the actual `myStuff` map is modified (by some method of your `StuffHandler` class), every other class that has called `getStuff()` will see this modification.

Answer (score 2):

> given that CHMs are meant to be used by only one thread at a time

This is simply not accurate. The "Concurrent" part of `ConcurrentHashMap` means "safe for concurrent use by multiple threads." As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) notes:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high
>   expected concurrency for updates.

If you do not want your consumer to be able to mutate the `Map` you can either create a copy (then cannot even see updates) or wrap with [unmodifiableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) (can see updates).

Answer (score 1):

If you want each object that gets the map to get the same data, and have changes made by one class be visible to the other classes, you want to return 'myStuff' directly.

If you want each object that gets the map to have their own copy, and if you don't want changes made by one object to be seen by the other object, return a copy of 'myStuff'.